# Static assertion on template parameter not called

Tags: c++, templates

Assuming these two helper structs:

```
struct A { static constexpr bool Value = false; };
template <bool DEFERRED> struct B { static_assert(DEFERRED, "Failed"); };
```

And the follow class that uses it:

```
class XYZ {
public:
    template <class X = A, class Y = B<X::Value>> int SomeFunction() {...}

....
int main() {
    XYZ xyz;
    xyz.SomeFunction();
}
```

I don't see why the static assertion is not called, since template boolean DEFERRED should evaluate to false. However when I instantiate template type Y inside the function body, the static assertion is called.

Is there a way to trigger the static_assert evaluation without instantiating template type Y? (Or an easier / smarter way)

EDIT: I should mention I'm using GCC 5.0

Thank you.

Comment: "Static_assert" is a compile time assertion. It works when you have local bool_constexpr. Added some tested code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my question was misunderstood. My issue was that I was expecting the compiler to evaluate the body when the type was instantiated, not when it was used in a declaration. Either way I resolved my issue by doing the following (Using the boilerplate code):

```
template <bool DEFERRED> struct B {
    static constexpr bool Proxy = DEFERRED;
    static_assert(Proxy , "Failed");
};
template <class X = A, bool T = B<X::Value>::Proxy> int SomeFunction() {...}
```

Which forced the compiler to evaluate the body and trigger any static assertions.

Answer (score 1):

You can see a class as a blueprint for an object, and you can see a template as a blueprint for a class.

A template is just a template, it is not a class until you instantiate the template into a class, which you don't do until the declaration of the `xyz` variable.

Comment: I was under the impression that when the class type had been template instantiated (For the lack of a better word) the compiler would propagate and "replace" the template parameters and in turn execute any floating static_assert(s). Not when the type was used in a variable instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

**since template boolean DEFERRED should evaluate to false (in your question)**....

This is because of the `constexpr` in `struct A`.

`constexpr` specifier makes it possible to evaluate the `bool` value at compile time

Take out `constexpr` and build, you will notice the difference.

**Why your `static_assert` is not working:**

`static_assert`  expects a `bool_constexpr`.

`DEFERRED` is just bool and the value is known inside the template class body only if we instantiate.

Try with below code, I added another `bool constexpr` inside `struct B` naming `test`. And pass that variable to `static_assert`. Now your `static_assert` works.

```
//g++  5.4.0

#include <iostream>

struct A { static constexpr bool Value = false; };
template <bool DEFERRED> struct B { 
    static constexpr bool test =  false;
     static_assert(test, "Failed");
};

class XYZ {
public:
    template <class X = A, class Y = B<X::Value>> int SomeFunction()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};


int main()
{
    XYZ xyz;
    xyz.SomeFunction();
}
```

You will notice the output:

```
source_file.cpp:8:6: error: static assertion failed: Failed
      static_assert(test, "Failed");
      ^
```

Now change the `test` value in `struct B` to `true`.

It works, no errors.

There is another scenario, assign `DEFERRED` to `test` variable as shown below:

```
template <bool DEFERRED> struct B { 
    static constexpr bool test =  DEFERRED;
     static_assert(test, "Failed");
};
```

The above said `static_assert` works only if you instantiate in main(), something like below.

```
B<false> b;
```